# A project which specifies sql server 2016 as the target platform cannot be published to sql server 2014

Tags: sql, visual-studio, publish

I tried publishing a database in Visual Studio, and I get this error:

> A project which specifies sql server 2016 as the target platform
> cannot be published to sql server 2014

How do I select to publish to SQL Server 2016, in Visual Studio?
Is there an option that I missed?
Or do I have no other choice but to target SQL Server 2014?

Comment: There is a piece of meta data somewhere in the project where you can change the target back to 2014.   It might be in the properties window of the project.   The amount of differences is very low and there would be workarounds between 2014 and 2016 for the few cases it is an issue.

Comment: As long as it does not use JSON functionality as I believe that was new in 2016.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Target SQL Version is part of the Project Properties.

[image: SQL Project Properties for Target]